# Does the VBA MSXML2 object support the use of a PAC file?

Tags: vba, pac

I am writing a VBA Excel add-in that uses the MSXML2 object to retrieve data over http. Not strictly a web browser; it just happens to be using the http protocol on port 80.

I know that if the user's Internet Explorer is set up to use a proxy server, then this will automatically pick up their proxy settings.

A user asked me about support for "Proxy.PAC" files, which I know nothing about.
After a little bit of googling, this looks like something that gets used on the browser level.

If a user has a PAC file, can the MSXML2 file use this information to direct its request properly?
Is this automatically supported?
Or is there some extra VBA code I need to add?
Or does the concept of a PAC file only work in a proper browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to figure out more about PAC files, and did an experiment of my own.  It seems like the MSXML2 object actually does respect the PAC file logic, so the answer is "no action necessary".